# Why do events commonly use EventHandler, even when no arguments need to be passed?

Tags: c#, events

It is common practice in C# when creating an event, to define it as follows, taken [from an example in the .NET Framework Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx):

```
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public CustomEventArgs(string s)
    {
        msg = s;
    }
    private string msg;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return msg; }
    } 
}

...

public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender, CustomEventArgs a);
```

Often, I create events which don't need any arguments at all. I usually implement this simply using `Action` for the event handler type.

```
public event Action LogonScreenExited;
```

I was wondering whether there is any reason why one would want to follow the 'traditional' pattern. Perhaps events like this indicate a design flaw? My reasoning however for using `Action` is [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), why implement something (and even show intent of) when it isn't used?

Comment: Seems to me that the .Net Framework BCL classes are not responsible for determining whether or not your code will "need" the usual `object sender` and args. The same criteria could be applied when creating custom events. The author of the event may not know up front whether the consumer will actually need these args.

Comment: Of course it's OK, however I think you should provide at least 1 argument to pass data in case you want to change the behavior of notifying event. Currently notifying the event is enough but may be in future update, you may want to provide more data on the event, so following the traditional pattern is not really bad.

Comment: For the event args part, I understand your argument and would like to see an answer too, but the `sender` portion, that is extremely useful for code re-use, I can have the same function subscribed to many different events and by checking the `sender` I can see which object I need to be operating on.

Comment: @KingKing When at some point data _is_ passed, what would prevent you from just changing the event handler type? You would have to adjust it either way in case you want strongly typed arguments. Although, ... you could of course always implement a custom empty type as placeholder.

Comment: @StevenJeuris not clear what you mean, an `event` is just a special kind of `delegate`, so **you don't have to follow any pattern**, like as **you don't have to name public method with first letter capitalized** in C#, but it's some kind of convention, popular style. The `EventHandler` is also ready defined for you. I bet that using `EventHandler` will make your code look better and like as `.NET` source code (not your own code).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is not a requirement, merely a design guide.

You'll need to keep in mind that you cannot predict how the client code is going to use the event and you cannot predict the future.  The *sender* argument is useful to the client programmer, it lets him use a single event handler method that handles events from multiple event sources.  Deriving from EventArgs is useful since it lets you refactor the event, deriving from the original base class and adding extra arguments, without breaking the client code.  You are free to ignore the benefits of this approach.

Comment: Good point, allowing to introduce changes without breaking existing code which relies on it does seems to be the main advantage. It does beg the question how often that would be needed for events without arguments. :)

Comment: “without breaking the client code.” Note that this is only API compatibility, not ABI compatibility. To keep the ABI backward compatible, you must declare a delegate type rather than use `EventHandler<T>` or `EventHandler`.

Answer (score 9):

Because you can write a generic event handler and use it for many different kind of events (like a logging facility) taking advantage of [contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) in delegates.

Here's an example from the msdn:

```
// Event hander that accepts a parameter of the EventArgs type. 
private void MultiHandler(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // You can use a method that has an EventArgs parameter, 
    // although the event expects the KeyEventArgs parameter. 
    this.button1.KeyDown += this.MultiHandler;

    // You can use the same method  
    // for an event that expects the MouseEventArgs parameter. 
    this.button1.MouseClick += this.MultiHandler;

}
```

Other than this, it is only a design guide, a *recommended* way. Following it makes your code maintainable and consistend with the rest of the .NET, helping a lot who will be using your classes.

Comment: Hey, the OP talks about **custom event**, not the **.NET event**.

Comment: "I was wondering whether there is any reason why one would want to follow the 'traditional' pattern" - I gave a reason

Comment: Although this is a good point, I wonder how often you actually need these 'common' handlers. They would only make sense in case you don't need to know about the specific handler type, otherwise you end up type checking and casting. Your given example could make sense e.g. when you need to know whether the user did any input at all. In my experience scenarios like this happen rarely.

Comment: @StevenJeuris actually that is just a design guide, it is the common way to do events in the .NET. Probably this is the best reason: if you are writing a library it surely is a good idea to stick with it, it will all be more maintainable and easy to use

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on classes which you have no access to modify their codes.
Passing extra event arge which is instantiated from you own EventArgs derived class will let you to pass extra arguments in the future.

Also your code will support `EventHandler<T>` class which its T should be derived from EventArgs class.